# What if a duplicate is being voted on as not helpful by anonymous users?

Tags: discussion

I'm using the [review tools](https://askubuntu.com/tools/post-feedback/least-helpful?filter=all) to see which questions are being voted on as useful and not useful by anonymous/low-rep users.

- [how to uninstall unity in ubuntu 11.04, not disable it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61775/how-to-uninstall-unity-in-ubuntu-11-04-not-disable-it) (-18)
- [How to remove unity and unity-2d?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62004/how-to-remove-unity-and-unity-2d) (-17)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/66520/how-to-downgrade-11-10-to-11-04

And so on. I'm thinking people are landing on these pages and then not realizing they can follow the link to the actual question, is there anything we can or should do about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate on MSO - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125220/automatically-redirect-anonymous-user-from-unanswered-duplicate-question-to-corr

Comment: *marks the question as not helpful*

Comment: Excellent news http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125807/172094

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Kevin Montrose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125807/172094), the next update to Stack Exchange will redirect anonymous users through duplicates transparently, provided the duplicate has zero answers.

The solution, then, seems to be making sure that answers to popular duplicates get properly merged into their target question. The dupe question itself will remain, so its SEO benefits will as well.

**Edit**: I've checked while logged out: this feature is now in effect. A discussion about merging/deletion/redirect policy for duplicates has sprouted up [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2778/automatic-duplicate-redirection-sop).

Comment: Great news, I've been flagging dupes that have potentially good answers as merge candidates, this makes everything much slicker.

Answer (score 4):

If the question is a clear duplicate and has useful answers, you can consider merging it into the original.

The drawback would be that you'd lose out on the terms/phrases from the duplicate appearing in the Google results thanks to being phrased differently than the original.

Comment: We've already found one or two that had more traffic on the duplicate than the original, so we at least have an indication of when merging in the other direction might be a better option.